# Mostrar video en thumbs react boostrap carousel

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-carousel

tengo un `carousel` con `react boostrap carousel` y en los `thumbs` me muestra las imágenes que tengo pero también tengo un video el cual no se muestra allí

Adjunto codigo jsx

```
<div className="card">
      <ReactCarousel 
        showArrows={true}
        showStatus={false}
        swipeable={true}
        showIndicators={false}
        infiniteLoop={true}
        emulateTouch={true}
        useKeyboardArrows
      >
        {slides.map((slide) => (
          <div className="image-wrapper" key={slide.id}>
            {slide.type === "video" ? (
              <video  controls>
                <source src={slide.src} type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            ) : (
              <img src={slide.src} alt="media" />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </ReactCarousel>
    </div>
```

Adjunto imagen de como se ve

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

intente creando un div con los `thumbs` y pasando con `index` por medio de parametros al carousel pero no me funciono.

Alguno puede brindarme una idea de como puedo hacer para que se muestre ahí como las imágenes?

Gracias

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el resultado que esperas, en la imágen que adjuntaste veo el video....

Comment: Correcto, en la imagen sale el video normal pero tengo 3 imagenes y 1 video, y si te fijas abajo en los thumbs solo me salen las 3 imagenes que poseo pero no una imagen o una miniatura del video

Comment: Entiendo, encontré un hilo en el proyecto de github y parece que ahora lo soportan, te dejo unos demos que tienen: http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/storybook/?path=/story/02-advanced--youtube-autoplay-with-custom-thumbs

Comment: Estuve viendo y parece que usan una librería aparte para un react-player y parece que con ese se crea el thumbnail y todo... el ejemplo está hecho en youtube, no sé si funcionará con otro video.

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar, publique la solución. Gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió mucho el demo que me enviaste

Answer (score 1):

La solución para el inconveniente que tenia fue el siguiente.

Realice una funcion llamada `customRenderThumbs`

```
  const customRenderThumb = () =>
    list.map((prop, id) => {
      return <img key={id} src={prop.poster} alt="image" />;
    });
```

Y pasarla a mi componente `Carousel` por medio de la propiedad `renderThumbs`

```
<ReactCarousel
   renderThumbs={customRenderThumb}
 >
```

Como funciona es que mi list es un array de objetos que contiene lo siguiente

```
images: [
      {
        src: Apartment1,
        type: 'img',
        poster: Apartment1
      },
      {
        src: Apartment2,
        type: 'img',
        poster: Apartment2
      },
      {
        src: Apartment3,
        type: 'img',
        poster: Apartment3
      },
      {
        src: Video,
        type: 'video',
        poster: Apartment1
      },
    ]
```

El atributo poster será la imagen que ponemos en nuestro `thumb` para mostrar, de esta manera pondremos la imagen que queremos mostrar y funciona perfectamente.

Adjunto el `código` completo de mi `carousel`

```
export const Carousel2 = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const { id } = useParams();

  const property = housesData.find((house) => {
    return house.id === parseInt(id);
  });
  const list = property.images;
  const handlePause = () => {
    videoRef.current.pause();
  };

  const customRenderThumb = () =>
    list.map((prop, id) => {
      return <img key={id} src={prop.poster} alt="image" />;
    });

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <ReactCarousel
        showArrows={true}
        showStatus={false}
        swipeable={true}
        showIndicators={false}
        infiniteLoop={true}
        emulateTouch={true}
        useKeyboardArrows
        onChange={handlePause}
        renderThumbs={customRenderThumb}
      >
        {list.map((prop, id) => (
          <div className="image-wrapper" key={id}>
            {prop.type === "video" ? (
              <video ref={videoRef} muted controls autoPlay>
                <source src={prop.src} type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            ) : (
              <img src={prop.src} alt="image" />
            )}
          </div>
        ))}
      </ReactCarousel>
    </div>
  );
};
```